# Inserting rows to datatable from another GridView in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have 1 gridview filled with data, 1 gridview empty and 1 button.
First I select multiple rows in gridview with data, and then what I want to accomplish is when I press the button I want to transfer selected rows to empty datagridView.

Hope that is clear to you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to copy selected rows from the dataGridView1 to dataGridView2:

```
Dim boundItemLists = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().Select(Function(r) (TryCast(r.DataBoundItem, DataRowView)).Row).ToList()
        boundItemLists.ForEach(Function(r) (TryCast(dataGridView2.DataSource, DataTable)).ImportRow(r))
```

In this code snippet I suppose that data sources of both DataGridView controls have the same columns. If columns are different you have to write additional code to map data source of the source grid to a row in the destination grid.